# jqplot best alternative for polar and radar chart

Tags: jquery, html, jqplot, polar-coordinates, radar-chart

I'm looking for an alternative to plot polar data. I need to realize a charts like [this](http://www.google.it/imgres?um=1&hl=it&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3ait%3aofficial&channel=fflb&biw=1440&bih=797&tbm=isch&tbnid=aH-DqmSfSRvHUM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.contentandmotion.co.uk/blog/intent-index/&docid=ExLaf6tRRrIljM&imgurl=http://www.contentandmotion.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/RF-Intent-Index.png&w=600&h=473&ei=Uh2dUIvDH8HbtAaTnYDoAQ&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=340&vpy=38&dur=747&hovh=199&hovw=253&tx=190&ty=114&sig=114523337351869053473&page=1&tbnh=144&tbnw=183&start=0&ndsp=23&ved=1t:429,r:1,s:0,i:69) with dinamic options like [this](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/kcp_pdf.html).

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally require these:

1. [Highcharts JS](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar)
2. [canvasXpress](http://canvasxpress.org/network.html)
3. [D3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) with demo [here](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111116/gears.html).

they might look a little fancy to you but im sure you will like it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will give a try to D3.js! It seems very powerful.